# Calculate field with previous value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm facing a problem relate to calculate value a field but using value on previous line. In table RATE with data

```
ID Original Rate      Capital
-- ------------------ -------
 1 50                       1
 2 50 + 1                   1
 3 50 + 1 + 1               1
 4 50 + 1 + 1 + 2           2
 5 50 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2       2
```

The formula is : **Original Rate(n) = Original Rate(n-1) + Capital**

In original, I have 1 rows with Original Rate is 50, and I want the next value should be pre-Original Rate + Capital.

I also tried to use [Lag Function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lag.php), but it seem not applied for calculated field.

Please help me if you guys have any idea about this case ?

Thank you for your time !

---

**Update for new case :**

```
+----+---------------+------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | Original Rate | Type | Capital | Rate1 | Rate2 | Rate3 |
+----+---------------+------+---------+-------+-------+-------+ 
|  1 |            50 |    1 |       2 | 0.1   |       |       | 
|  2 |            50 |    1 |       2 | 0.1   |       |       |
|  3 |            50 |    1 |       2 | 0.1   |       |       |
|  4 |            50 |    2 |       1 |       | 0.2   |       |
|  5 |            50 |    3 |       5 |       |       | 0.3   |
+----+---------------+------+---------+-------+-------+-------+

New Rate (n) = New Rate (n-1) + Original Rate * IF(Type=1,Rate1*capital,IF(Type=2,Rate2*capital),Rate3*capital)
```

And the output I expect is in last column as below :

```
+----+---------------+------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
| ID | Original Rate | Type | Capital | Rate1 | Rate2 | Rate3 |     |
+----+---------------+------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
|  1 |            50 |    1 |       2 | 0.1   |       |       |  10 |
|  2 |            50 |    1 |       2 | 0.1   |       |       |  20 |
|  3 |            50 |    1 |       2 | 0.1   |       |       |  30 |
|  4 |            50 |    2 |       4 |       | 0.2   |       |  70 |
|  5 |            50 |    3 |       5 |       |       | 0.3   | 145 |
+----+---------------+------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
```

Any advice and suggestions are welcome !

**[Update 17-Apr-2017]**
I implemented the extraction using **Recursion with recursive WITH**

```
WITH RATE_MASTER AS (ID, RATE)
(
    SELECT 1, ORIGINALRATE FROM RATE WHERE ID = 1
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT ID,
    CASE 
        WHEN TYPE = 1 THEN RATE + Rate1*Capital 
        WHEN TYPE = 2 THEN RATE + Rate2*Capital
        WHEN TYPE = 3 THEN RATE + Rate3*Capital
    END AS RATE
    
    FROM RATE, RATE_MASTER
    WHERE RATE_MASTER.ID = RATE.ID - 1
)
SELECT * FROM RATE_MASTER;
```

**It worked properly !**

**[Closed]**

Comment: please post some sample data and the expected result in a tabular format as formatted text.

Comment: can you please click on Run code snippet ? I also updated a table with data .

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE rate ( id, capital ) AS
  SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT id,
       50 + SUM( capital ) OVER ( ORDER BY id )
          - FIRST_VALUE( capital ) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS rate,
       capital
FROM   rate;
```

**Output**:

```
ID RATE CAPITAL
-- ---- -------
 1   50       1
 2   51       1
 3   52       1
 4   54       2
 5   56       2
```

Comment: Thanks MT0, It work on example data. I am going to apply to my case and back soon !